# BaseGameUtils: Initiate SignIn/SignOut from surface view

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, google-play-games

I made my app in a surface view and it all works well. I wanted to add leaderboards to my app since it seemed appropriate. Problem is that I can't set up the google play signin/out system.

I would like to run the `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()` and `signOut()` methods from within the surface view's update method. I tried all the ways I can think of. This is tricky since it's a non-static method and I don't have access to the activity's instance.

Is there a bypass, or is there a way to access the game's activity object?

Comment: I found a solution. What I did was I made a thread in the main activity class that checks to see if one of the two booleans I made as set to true. Ex: If the signin boolean is true, then it will initiate a sign in, same for signout. So all I need to do now is change the value of the booleans from the surface view and there you go!

Comment: Awesome! Add your solution in an update to the question.